# What kind of power could be stronger than light and shadow?

Tags: magic, moons, super-powers, stars, sunlight

I am creating a world where exist 2 main types of magic users: the ones with the ability to control the light of the sun and the ones with the ability to control the darkness of the shadows/moon. However, I'm having trouble coming up with a 3rd type of user. This 3rd kind is meant to be stronger than those above, and should have a similar theme. Is there a type of magic, preferably related to the stars, which is classically known to either encompass the previous 2 or be simultaneously opposite to them? The selection here is made through the one which seems to make the most sense within the context of these 3 main sources: light, darkness and [redacted] , with [redacted] being normally considered as above/ superior to the previous 2.

Comment: Time, space, void, aether, radiant, all your powers combined, death, life, mirrors, cheese, etc. There are a lot of elements that can potentially be superior to 'light' and 'darkness', you'll need to be a lot more specific if you don't want this to be closed as 'opinion-based'.

Comment: This is the kernel or starting point of an interesting question! We're going to need to know more about how your world works: what other powers exist, and how those powers might interact with or counteract one another. Without knowing more, we really can't extrapolate a sensible answer, and thus all answers will be useless opinion.

Comment: Ejaculating spider webs from your wrists, with great power comes great responsibility. In the movie spiderman, spider guy shots a lot of webs on his bedrum lamp neutralizing that light power source

Comment: @Halfthawed cheese? I like cheese, but I find Vieux Boulogne overpowering. :grin:

Answer (score 3):

**Void.**

Light is defined by where it is not.  If everything is the same brightness, nothing can be seen.  Shadow is defined by the light.  With no light there can be no shadow.  The light magic and the shadow magic are the same magic, even if they don't realize it.  They are flip sides of the same coin.

The void strips the power from both of them.  Void is the absence of light.

Of course in the best traditions of YA fiction, light and shadow will combine their strengths to defeat Void.

Comment: I don't feel bad at all that Halfthawed included void in that list under the OP, because cheese was in there and that is all anyone read including me because I am hungry.

Comment: Cheese was *tenth* on the list, void was third. It's not that I'm accusing you of lying, I just find it odd that you start lists from the wrong end, read the first entry, and go 'Well, that made me hungry, guess I'll stop reading the list now'.

Comment: Void of any any explanation, void is no more an answer than cheese.  I think it is the justification that makes this its own answer.

Comment: @Halfthawed - I actually stopped reading that comment after the first word.

Comment: @Willk That's fair. I don't know what I was expecting actually, starting with that word.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of stuff that can beat them

Light is movement of photons in a specific wave length, darkness/shadow is the absence of light, so they're the other side of the same coin. 
You can shoot a laser to me, but it will take some time to move from you to me (light is the fastest thing in the universe, but even then it takes 8 minutes for the light of the sun to reach us, so it's not instantaneous).

Time is a movement frame. If i stop time your laser will never reach, if i turn it back it never came out. if i stop time, grab you, put you where the laser was targeting, and put you in an eternal loop of 2 seconds (enough to feel the pain) you'll end wishing you never even meet me.

But it doesn't even have to be something as grandiose as time, a really good telekinesis user can stop movement in the same way, or if it was having a bad day, stop all movement from the molecules of your body and watch how you disintegrate, like when you put something in liquid nitrogen and then hit it against the table.

Heck, even a good mirror is enough to give you some troubles like that.

The bottom line is that every power can become a great weapon or a great failure, if you're creative enough.

Answer (score 0):

**Either a mix of both or matter/energy.**

It is said that light and dark are two sides of a single coin (in our world one is the presence of light, the other is the absence of it), so one who controls both can easily combine them into something better than each one separately.

On another point of view, you could use an extension of matter control, meaning turning matter into energy and vice versa. This isn't absent in stars, as the light from our sun and any other stars usually come from fusion reactions (our sun fuses hydrogen into helium). That means you can control matter, turn it into energy, mold it into puppets, compress it, fuse it into reactions, cause explosions hotter than our sun's core (see [tsar bomba](https://www.atomicheritage.org/history/tsar-bomba)), etc. Making clustering enough matter is also a frightening thing (condense enough matter into a dense enough cluster and you'll get a self sustaining system with such a gravitational pull that nothing, not even light, can escape, aka a black hole)